# How to count how many time a recursive function calls itself without using any vars

Tags: scala, recursion

I have a function called collatz and I need to find how many times it calls itself, but I'm not allowed to use any vars.

The function works perfectly with vars but i have to use vals.

Comment: pass the number of calls as an argument to the function which will get incremented on every call

Answer (score 1):

In case sinanspd's answer does not answer your question, here is some example code.

Let us say your function collatz has a signature as follows:

```
def collatz(input: Type1): Type2 = ???
```

The way to count how many times it is called is to either modify collatz itself, or else to use some wrapper function.

```
def counter(oldCount: Int, fun: Type1 => Type2, input: Type1): (Int, Type2) = {
  val output = fun(input)
  (oldCount + 1, output)
}
```

The first time you call counter, call it with oldCount set to 0. Every time you call counter, pass in the old version of count. The first value of your output tuple will be the new count.

Comment: I'm quite new but like what does the fun: Type1 => Type2 mean?

Comment: It's a function from Type1 to Type2. I have assumed here that your function collatz has the signature `def collatz(input: Type1): Type2`. So just pass in collatz where you expect fun in counter. Of course, in your implementation, you have to give fun the type that you expect for collatz based on collatz's type signature. If you have any more questions, feel free to ask.